# mysql query - how can I create this query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have an issue creating a query.

Lets say I have this data in a table: field ids:

> 10 20 30 40 30 20 60 70 20

I need to display all results, but this way:

> 10 20 30 40 60 70 20 30 20

As you can see, I sorted them, but it must take only unique values until it has no more, then add the left applying the same filter... only uniques... an so until it displays all results on the database.

Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: umm.. have you tried `ORDER BY` `ASC` ? I guess my question is: have you tried anything at all?

Comment: Very easy with `ROW_NUMBER` **[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5a4ce/2/0)**. Feel free to translate to MySQL

Comment: I have tried all the I know @CodeGodie. Group by: takes only unique values. If I group by with 2 fields, then I get all the values but "sorted" them so I get duplicates one by one 10,20,20,20,30,30,40,60,70

Comment: @lad2025 thanks, it looks interesting. I will try to apply this.

Comment: Very good solution lad2025.

Comment: Try putting them in a histogram, iterating across the histogram's keys in ascending order, and writing to a list whenever > 0 and removing from the histogram whenever == 0. EDIT: This would be an alternative solution in your high-level programming language, not as easy in straight SQL.

Comment: @lad2025, write out your solution as an answer to the question, please.

Comment: @ShotgunNinja Done ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a sequence number for the ids, the ordering by the sequence number and the id.

```
SELECT id
FROM
(
    SELECT id, @cnt := IF(id = @id, @cnt + 1, 1), @id := id, @cnt AS cnt
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT id
        FROM table1
        ORDER BY id
    ) sub1
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @cnt := 0, @id := 0) sub0
) sub2
ORDER BY cnt, id
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I need. It works as expected. Marked as correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this, the query should order first all the rows with value 1 after that 2 and so on

```
SET @prev_value = NULL;
SET @rank_count = 0;

SELECT id, rank_column, CASE
    WHEN @prev_value = rank_column THEN @rank_count
    WHEN @prev_value := rank_column THEN @rank_count := @rank_count + 1
END AS rank
FROM rank_table
ORDER BY rank_column
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting from MySQL 8.0 you could use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
CREATE TABLE tab(col INT);
INSERT INTO tab(col)
VALUES (10),(20), (30), (40), (30), (20),  (60), (70), (20);

SELECT t.col
FROM tab t
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col ORDER BY col), t.col;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=eb52088156081941bc6cb6160c8f70c2)**

Output:

```
┌─────┐
│ col │
├─────┤
│  10 │
│  20 │
│  30 │
│  40 │
│  60 │
│  70 │
│  20 │
│  30 │
│  20 │
└─────┘
```